# Extract GPS information to "steady" and "Moving"

Tags: android, r, gps, geolocation, geospatial

I have questions related with GPS data. 
I have data looks like

[image]

The question is, I want to extract information from that data to the value3, I want to fill value3 with "steady" and "moving".

steady and moving based on values from latitude and longitude, but I also still confused because when I tried to plot.

The example :

```
35.1754255,126.9130674
35.1754281,126.9130184
35.1754225,126.9130536
35.1807405,126.9055772
```

The result of plot:
[image]

Values 1 ~ 3 are moving but just only little moving not much, so maybe the value3 will be fill with "steady", "short moving", "long moving" but I am still do not know about the threshold values to define which is short, and long.

My second question is how I can generate the value3 using R code. Actually I can compare the next values and the current values, if different means moving, if not means steady, but I am still confused about short and long moving.

The Output of dput() from my data

```
> dput(loc)
structure(list(time = c("2014-06-30 08:26:36", "2014-06-30 08:31:30", 
"2014-06-30 08:36:30", "2014-06-30 08:41:30", "2014-06-30 08:46:30", 
"2014-06-30 08:51:30", "2014-06-30 08:56:31", "2014-06-30 09:01:30", 
"2014-06-30 09:06:30", "2014-06-30 09:11:30", "2014-06-30 09:16:30", 
"2014-06-30 09:21:30", "2014-06-30 09:26:30", "2014-06-30 09:31:30", 
"2014-06-30 09:36:30", "2014-06-30 09:41:30", "2014-06-30 09:46:30", 
"2014-06-30 09:51:52", "2014-06-30 09:56:30", "2014-06-30 10:01:30", 
"2014-06-30 10:06:53", "2014-06-30 10:11:30", "2014-06-30 10:16:52", 
"2014-06-30 10:21:30", "2014-06-30 10:26:30", "2014-06-30 10:31:30", 
"2014-06-30 10:36:51", "2014-06-30 10:41:30", "2014-06-30 10:46:54", 
"2014-06-30 10:51:51", "2014-06-30 10:57:30", "2014-06-30 11:01:51", 
"2014-06-30 11:06:30", "2014-06-30 11:11:51", "2014-06-30 11:16:30", 
"2014-06-30 11:21:51", "2014-06-30 11:26:30", "2014-06-30 11:31:30", 
"2014-06-30 11:36:52", "2014-06-30 11:41:30", "2014-06-30 11:46:51", 
"2014-06-30 11:51:30", "2014-06-30 11:56:53", "2014-06-30 12:01:32", 
"2014-06-30 12:07:30", "2014-06-30 12:11:51", "2014-06-30 12:16:33", 
"2014-06-30 12:21:30", "2014-06-30 12:26:30", "2014-06-30 12:31:51", 
"2014-06-30 12:36:30", "2014-06-30 12:41:36", "2014-06-30 12:46:30", 
"2014-06-30 12:52:10", "2014-06-30 12:56:30", "2014-06-30 13:01:30", 
"2014-06-30 13:06:30", "2014-06-30 13:11:30", "2014-06-30 13:16:30", 
"2014-06-30 13:21:30", "2014-06-30 13:26:30", "2014-06-30 13:31:30", 
"2014-06-30 13:36:30", "2014-06-30 13:41:30", "2014-06-30 13:46:30", 
"2014-06-30 13:51:30", "2014-06-30 13:56:30", "2014-06-30 14:01:30", 
"2014-06-30 14:06:55", "2014-06-30 14:11:19", "2014-06-30 14:16:19", 
"2014-06-30 14:21:19", "2014-06-30 14:26:19", "2014-06-30 14:31:19", 
"2014-06-30 14:36:19", "2014-06-30 14:41:19", "2014-06-30 14:46:19", 
"2014-06-30 14:51:19", "2014-06-30 14:56:19", "2014-06-30 15:01:19", 
"2014-06-30 15:06:19", "2014-06-30 15:11:19", "2014-06-30 15:16:19", 
"2014-06-30 15:21:19", "2014-06-30 15:26:19", "2014-06-30 15:31:19", 
"2014-06-30 15:36:19", "2014-06-30 15:41:19", "2014-06-30 15:46:19", 
"2014-06-30 15:51:19", "2014-06-30 15:56:19", "2014-06-30 16:01:19", 
"2014-06-30 16:06:19", "2014-06-30 16:11:19", "2014-06-30 16:16:20", 
"2014-06-30 16:21:19", "2014-06-30 16:26:19", "2014-06-30 16:31:19", 
"2014-06-30 16:36:19", "2014-06-30 16:41:19"), type = c("location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location", "location", "location", "location", 
"location", "location", "location"), value1 = c("35.1754255", 
"35.1754281", "35.1754225", "35.1753982", "35.1753991", "35.1753997", 
"35.1754333", "35.1754143", "35.1754126", "35.1754142", "35.1753987", 
"35.1754178", "35.1754176", "35.1753914", "35.1754066", "35.1753833", 
"35.1753883", "35.174465", "35.174465", "35.1735813", "35.1744781", 
"35.1735813", "35.174502", "35.1749091", "35.1749091", "35.1749091", 
"35.1744991", "35.1749091", "35.1751931", "35.1748972", "35.1755879", 
"35.1759928", "35.1759928", "35.1763946", "35.1763946", "35.1763882", 
"35.1763882", "35.1762131", "35.1760547", "35.1760547", "35.1774352", 
"35.1774352", "35.1785821", "35.1785821", "35.1773562", "35.1807058", 
"35.1807058", "35.1813436", "35.1802903", "35.1807615", "35.1807615", 
"35.1807405", "35.1807405", "35.1805536", "35.1805536", "35.1808169", 
"35.1797636", "35.1836812", "35.1836812", "35.1897643", "35.1898214", 
"35.1897615", "35.1897765", "35.1897157", "35.1896921", "35.1897299", 
"35.18975", "35.1897503", "35.1897673", "35.1897539", "35.1897932", 
"35.1897702", "35.1897627", "35.189763", "35.1897438", "35.1898021", 
"35.1897853", "35.1897405", "35.1897803", "35.1897844", "35.1897624", 
"35.1897769", "35.1897656", "35.1897265", "35.1897488", "35.1897599", 
"35.1897477", "35.1897951", "35.189759", "35.1897624", "35.1897692", 
"35.1898468", "35.1897727", "35.1897624", "35.1897958", "35.189817", 
"35.1897391", "35.1897317", "35.189745", "35.1897624"), value2 = c("126.9130674", 
"126.9130184", "126.9130536", "126.9130597", "126.9130549", "126.9130598", 
"126.9130484", "126.9130638", "126.9130687", "126.9130553", "126.913074", 
"126.9130686", "126.9130779", "126.9130496", "126.9130196", "126.9130507", 
"126.9130474", "126.9135807", "126.9135807", "126.9119189", "126.9137426", 
"126.9119189", "126.9137499", "126.9124954", "126.9124954", "126.9124954", 
"126.9137861", "126.9124954", "126.9142743", "126.9118689", "126.912267", 
"126.9131502", "126.9131502", "126.9130495", "126.9130495", "126.9131069", 
"126.9131069", "126.911819", "126.9121906", "126.9121906", "126.9123621", 
"126.9123621", "126.9093961", "126.9093961", "126.9041179", "126.9055765", 
"126.9055765", "126.904599", "126.9054961", "126.905568", "126.905568", 
"126.9055772", "126.9055772", "126.9052718", "126.9052718", "126.9050475", 
"126.9059447", "126.9052348", "126.9052348", "126.9063181", "126.9062802", 
"126.9063452", "126.9064237", "126.9065031", "126.9065168", "126.9063599", 
"126.9064195", "126.9064469", "126.9063441", "126.9063828", "126.9064423", 
"126.9063459", "126.9063602", "126.9063096", "126.9063355", "126.9063742", 
"126.9063253", "126.9063123", "126.9063434", "126.9063729", "126.906397", 
"126.9063288", "126.906282", "126.9062903", "126.9063502", "126.9063432", 
"126.9063004", "126.9063742", "126.9063343", "126.9063969", "126.9062847", 
"126.9063212", "126.9063034", "126.9063969", "126.9063237", "126.906375", 
"126.9063572", "126.9063514", "126.9062548", "126.906397"), value3 = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "")), .Names = c("time", "type", "value1", "value2", 
"value3"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to round up/down some digits? Not sure how many digits you want to round up/down. But, you can find it out doing some calculation, I think.

Comment: @jazzurro I do not have any knowledge about geospatial data, Is it ok to round up/down, do you know how many digits that I should use, If I want to round that data.

Comment: @rawr actually both of questions is similar, I want to fill columns value3 with steady, short moving and long moving, but I am still confuse to define short and long moving

Comment: @user46543 The way you want to define "long" and "short" seems to be your own choice. I just thought that it would be hard to see exact same geocode given some errors coming from GPS. I also had the impression that you would not want "little movement" somehow. But, it seems that you want to classify movements in three categories. Is that right?

Comment: @jazzurro yes, is there any way to know little movement and long movement, means library to processing spatial data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt. As I mentioned in the comments above, you want to define "short movement" and "long movement" by yourself. In R, you can use `lag()` in the `dplyr` package and calculate movement, for instance. I may be wrong, but 1 degree is about 111.32 km. So 0.0001 degree is about 11 meters. In this attempt, if this person moved more than 11 meters and less than 55 meters in both longitude and latitude, I considered the movement "little movement". Any longer movement is considered "long movement". Since I am not a gis professional, my approach may not be appropriate. But, I hope this gives you some ideas of what you would want to do.

P.S. If you have a large data, this `ifelse()` will slow down the process. You want to consider using the `data.table` package.

```
# Note: 1 degree = 111.32 km
#0.0001 degree  11.1132 m

# Convert character to numeric
mydf$value1 <- as.numeric(mydf$value1)
mydf$value2 <- as.numeric(mydf$value2)

library(dplyr)
select(mydf, -type, -value3) %>%
mutate(movement = ifelse(value1 == lag(value1) & value2 == lag(value2), "same",
                      ifelse(between(abs(value1 - lag(value1)), 0.0001, 0.0005) == TRUE &
                             between(abs(value2 - lag(value2)), 0.0001, 0.0005) == TRUE, "little", "long")))

# A part of the outcome
#33  2014-06-30 11:06:30 35.175993 126.91315     same
#34  2014-06-30 11:11:51 35.176395 126.91305   little
#35  2014-06-30 11:16:30 35.176395 126.91305     same
#36  2014-06-30 11:21:51 35.176388 126.91311     long
#37  2014-06-30 11:26:30 35.176388 126.91311     same
#38  2014-06-30 11:31:30 35.176213 126.91182     long
#39  2014-06-30 11:36:52 35.176055 126.91219   little
#40  2014-06-30 11:41:30 35.176055 126.91219     same
#41  2014-06-30 11:46:51 35.177435 126.91236     long
#42  2014-06-30 11:51:30 35.177435 126.91236     same
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I never use dplyr yet, is there any something missed in your code?, I could not run your code in my R studio the console still ask another commands, means "+  .....".

Comment: Ok, I can run it, only miss ")"

Comment: @user46543 Ah I am sorry about that.

Comment: @user46543 I revised my code. This is faster than the original.